# GZip not working in Laravel + OpenLiteSpeed

Tags: laravel, swoole, openlitespeed

I created a Laravel project and put it on the OpenLightSpeed web ​​server.

Everything works fine but gzip does not work!

Light Speed ​​cache settings are enabled but still gzip not enabled on port 8000.

[OpenLiteSpeed GZip Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlqT.png)

GZip Work perfectly outside of Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

After 24 hours, I found a solution

1- Set APP_URL to laravel public folder:

```
APP_URL=http://example.com/project_path/public
```

2- In `OpenLiteSpeed Console => Virtual Hosts => Example`
select View button and in `Context` tab click Edit button,
then in `Header Operations` field paste this code:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

And at the end, Restart OpenLiteSpeed!